# MaterializeCSS framework inside of ionic 2 app (third-party libs)

Tags: ionic2, materialize

I just want to use MaterializeCSS framework inside my ionic 2 app instead of native ionic components.

I read this [Third-party libs IONIC](http://ionicframework.com/docs/resources/third-party-libs/)

And I did :

"npm install --save materialize-css" - for installing materializeCSS in node_module folder

"npm install --save @types/materialize-css" - for typescript intellisense

And added in map.ts file:

```
import { Materialize } from 'materialize-css';
```

And this line in map.html file :

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>
```

Hoping that I will see beautiful MaterializeCSS button.

Unfortunatelly it doesnt work.

I tried also simply add css and js files in my main index.html file like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/materialize-css/bin/materialize.css">
<script src="../node_modules/materialize-css/bin/materialize.js"></script>
```

But somehow it doesnt see node_modules folder.

After hours of effort Im asking for help.

Comment: are you sure the css you are expecting isnt just being overridden? also it is `@types` which I assume is a typo in the question

Comment: I dont know if I ovveride this css styles. I only know that I cant use any MaterializeCss component. And yes @types are probably old typo.

Comment: you should check that with browser developer tools

Comment: I've just checked and I dont have any materializeCss css link/script tags.

Comment: I just found https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize though havent tried it.. looks easier to import..

Comment: Thanks but I know about that framework. It is not complete now and I want to use better alternative which is MaterializeCSS.